# A FTP server library

Tags: android, ftp

My question may sound stupid to anyone who has any knowledge about protocols and networking.

I'm looking for a java library that allows to run a FTP server, compatible with Android.
I tried Apache FTPServer, but I keep getting errors from Dalvik, or the library itself...

Searching on google doesn't give any interesting results, and since I never touched FTP programming before, I don't really know where to begin.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use : JFtp, but you can use too InputStream and OutputStream, BufferedStream to make a ftp client

Comment: Thanks for your help, but are you sure JFtp will be able to build a server? The client will be on a PC, not on the android device... Anyway I'll take a look at it.

Comment: JFtp Wasn't really helpful, but I looked in the direction of input and output streams, which works just fine. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Apache Mina FtpServer.

Check the following issue, you cannot stop a transfer in the middle. So terrible! I have spent 1 week with it in a project and suddenly found this restriction. It is not acceptable when transferring big files which user may choose to interrupt.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FTPSERVER-400

Also check the comment in ABOR impl.

- `ABOR <CRLF>`
- - This command tells the server to abort the previous FTP service command and
- any associated transfer of data. No action is to be taken if the previous
- command has been completed (including data transfer). The control connection
- is not to be closed by the server, but the data connection must be closed.
- Current implementation does not do anything. As here data transfers are not
- multi-threaded.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/) would work?